# How to Focus a TextArea that has an ngif

Tags: angular

I have the following Angular 2 component and I need the `textarea` with id `bannernote` to be focused as as soon as it becomes visible (`isEditEnabled`)

```
<div class="cont-notesbanner">
  <p class="triangle"></p>
  <h3 class="tit-notesbanner">Add notes:</h3>

  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <p
      class="p-notesbanner"
      *ngIf="!isEditEnabled"
      [ngClass]="currentAsset.notes.length === 0 ? 'it-place' : ''"
    >
      {{ currentAsset.notes.length === 0 ? "Add notes" : currentAsset.notes }}
    </p>
    <textarea 
      rows="4"
      cols="50"
      *ngIf="isEditEnabled"
      class="txt-notesbanner"
      name="bannernote"
      id="bannernote"
      rows="10"
      [(ngModel)]="currentAsset.notes"
      #bannernote
      onload="$('#bannernote').focus();"
    ></textarea>

    <div class="txt-right">
      <a class="smallButton" (click)="onCloseBannernotes()">Cancel</a>
      <a
        class="smallButton"
        (click)="onEditBannernotes()"
        *ngIf="!isEditEnabled"
        >Edit</a
      >
      <button type="submit" class="smallButton" *ngIf="isEditEnabled">
        Accept
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried to achieve that using the "onshow" and "onload" events as you can see above without success

I have also adde code inside this method that is called whenever the the button is toggled from "Edit" to "Accept" like `document.getElementById("bannernotes").focus`
But this does not work since when is being called that element has not been render because of the ngif has not been "executed"

```
onEditBannernotes() {
  this.isEditEnabled = !this.isEditEnabled;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the element in code with `@ViewChild`. Since the element may not be available initially, define the associated property as a setter, and set the focus in it. As suggested by [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639035/stefan) in a comment, check first if the element reference is defined; it becomes `undefined` when the element is removed from the view.

```
// Set the focus on the textarea as soon as it is available
@ViewChild("bannernote") set bannerNoteRef(ref: ElementRef) {
  if (!!ref) {
    ref.nativeElement.focus() ;
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vujjcu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Add a nullcheck to `ref`, else it might throw an error if you toggle it often. Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bbm7u

Comment: @Stefan - Thanks for the comment! I made the correction.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez - You don't like `!!ref`? It is safer than `ref !== undefined`.

Comment: i am noobie in angular (as you probably guessed) feel free to reverese the edit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@ViewChild()` decorator to retrieve your textearea element.
Put an identifier on your textarea like this: `<textarea #myTextarea></textarea>`

Don't forget to implements AfterViewInit interface.

```
 @ViewChild('myTextarea') textArea;

 ngAfterViewInit() {            
    this.textArea.focus();
 }
```

Comment: I have just tried this `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined`